# Pixel 2 XL will not connect to PC for Android Studio Debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, debugging, driver

I am trying to create a React-Native app and I need to connect my device to troubleshoot some issues that only occur on the physical device and not the simulator. For some reason I have never been able to connect my Pixel 2 XL to my PC. I am running Windows 10 and I have tried all of the following.

- Enabling developer mode and USB Debugging on my device.
- Uplugging and replugging my device 20+ times in a row.
- Changing the USB port I am using.
- Changing the USB connectivity settings in Developer Options > Default USB Configuration. (Options are: File Transfer, USB tethering, MIDI, PTP, No data transfer) I've tried them all.
- Restarting my device while it's plugged in
- Downloading the Google USB Driver (in Android Studio).
- Restarting my PC when the device is plugged in.
- Updating my PC, and updating my device.
- Checking Device Manager and trying to update the driver. (So the device used to show up with the yellow warning triangle next to it and trying to update the driver never worked. But now, the device doesn't even show up in Device Manager anymore)
- Factory Reset my phone.
- Downloaded Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 10 (Suggested by the google tech support)(I called them)

I feel like I've tried everything previously addressed in every Stack Overflow question on this issue.

Comment: Try changing the data cable.

Comment: Just bought a new one, waiting for it to ship.

Comment: Please reply if you get this working in future.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the issue. The data cable was the problem. If you have tried all the steps above, and nothing is working, buy a new cable. This one works great and seems very durable for my Pixel 2 X: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01N4OKUB8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N4OKUB8)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too - my Google Pixel 2 XL is about 9 months old. Was developing an app, so using USB debugging to debug the app as I built it. One day it mysteriously stopped working, though no issues with charging. I tried everything, including using all the different USB ports on my laptop, with no luck.

I eventually gave up and started using the emulator on Android Studio, and since I didn't need data transfer for anything else, I didn't send my phone for repair or anything.

A few weeks later it just started working again, all by itself...

I don't think I did anything to fix it - the moral of the story is, if you don't need it urgently, there's a chance it might just decide to work again!

Comment: it has since been switching between broken and working... ugh